# Share a link to a script in Microsoft Edge

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge, hyperlink, sharing

Edge has a Share option in the Right-click context menu, but the menu is very limited compared to the share menus on other platforms (e.g. iOS and Android).
Is there a way to have something like this?
[image]
In this example, I want to be able to share the URL to a Powershell script that'll open it in mpv.

Answer (score 0):

Edge menus are not very customizable, and neither is the Share menu.

To pass the link to an application, the most you can do is use "Copy link",
then use the copied link in the application.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you are after. You can share from MSEdge via eMail contacts. You have to define that via the 'Windows share option' to send via email to whoever is in your contact list from Outlook. You do not have to us that 'Copy Link' thingy first. It will assume the current link is what you want to use, or just use the 'Default email ' selection.